# center multiple nested div tags in one div container tag

Tags: css, html, tags, center

so i have one large div tag. the css style for this is:

```
.thumbcontainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

i have 4 div tags in that. the css style for them:

```
.thumbnails {
    float: left;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and finally the code:

```
<div class="thumbcontainer">

<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="gallery/1.jpg" style="" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="gallery/1-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="112"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="gallery/2.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img  src="gallery/2-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="112"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="gallery/3.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img  src="gallery/3-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="112"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="gallery/4.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img  src="gallery/4-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="112"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

</div> <!-- End of thumbcontainer div -->
```

it works, but there all left aligned with obviously 20(10x2) pixels in between them.
i tried changing thumbcontainer to text center aligned didnt do anything.

Comment: Do you want to center `.thumbnails` so each one is on a new line, or the entire group?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the float, and set the individual .thumbnail divs to display:inline-block.

To center the .thumbnail divs, you'll need to set the parent element to text-align:center.

So you'll be adding the following:

```
.thumbcontainer {
   text-align:center;
}

.thumbnails {
    float: none; // or remove float property
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I think i forgot to mention all of the thumbnails are on the same line? anyways, that makes them all in a vertical column and there still not centered.

Comment: Removing the float, displaying as "inline-block", and centering the parent div should work (see fiddle above) - if it does not, you probably have something else overriding the above style/s in your stylesheet.

Comment: what should i do? i literally copied the fiddle above. Heres a screenshot from dreamweaver showing what it is doing: http://imm.io/1gDTY wait i think i found it. i have an img style let me check real quick...

Comment: You might have your img set to display:block - check that?

Comment: Okay i fixed it, had img set to display:block i had that set for the header image, but i changed it to img.block and now the thumbnails work. Although in dreamweaver there centered in a column, but when i preview they go in a row.

Comment: Great to hear - must have been an icky Dreamweaver override

Answer (score 0):

You are using float:left, and that's why you find have all the thumbnails aligned left.
If you want to center align these elements within your div, try this:

```
   .thumbcontainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

.thumbnails {
display:inline-block;
margin:0px 10px;
```

}

Comment: same as other persons answer, does not work. These are images with links, and now line up in a vertical column after adding this. there also on the left side

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you trying to achieve? Mainly I am unsure about the container DIV.

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/jm9NW/1/) what you are looking for?

If not, please explain what is not yet working as intended - thanks!

PS: I add an explanation when you are 100% satisfied. ;-)